# Keep original colors of UIBarButtonItem's UIImage

Tags: xcode, swift5

How do I position a full colour logo to the top right side? When I try it goes one colour. When positioning in the center I don't get that issue.

Right side makes the logo blue:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.init(named: "inteliPOS_Iconic_Mark")
```

But in the title it's fine:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "inteliPOS_Iconic_Mark"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `UIBarButtonItem` with a `UIImageView` as custom view. That will keep the color of your image:

```
let logoImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "inteliPOS_Iconic_Mark"))
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoImageView)
```

If you use `UIBarButtonItem(image:)` the image will be used as a template and tinted according to the navigation bar's tint color.

When you use `UIBarButtonItem(customView:)` the image will be used as is.

Comment: Use an UIButton instead of an UIImageView